# C# Implicit Operator not working with reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, reflection

I am working on a requirement where in I need to check my ASP.NET Model Property for a value 000000.If the value is 000000 then it should be displayed as blank string.
I thought of achieving this using implicit operators.
Here is my model class

```
public class OrgName
        {
            private string Value { get; set; }

            public static implicit operator string(OrgName org)
            {
                return org.Value;
            }

            public static implicit operator OrgName(string value)
            {
                bool isAllZeros = value.Where(x => char.IsDigit(x)).All(x => x == '0');
                if (isAllZeros)
                    value = string.Empty;
                return new OrgName() { Value = value };
            }

        }
```

The problem is that we are using reflection to set property values.The above code does not work and the property is always displayed as blank.

Here is the reflection code

```
var prName = (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parentPrefix) ? objKey : parentPrefix + '.' + objKey);
                    var pi = modelMap[prName.ToLowerInvariant()].Property;

                var value = (collectionProperties.ContainsKey(objKey)) ? collectionProperties[objKey] : pi.GetValue(parentObj);

                if (value == null || pi.PropertyType.IsSimpleType())
                {
                    value = (prName == fieldToSet && pi.PropertyType.IsSimpleType())
                        ? (Convert.IsDBNull(valueToSet)) ? null : valueToSet
                        : createObject(pi.PropertyType);

                    var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType);

                    //check to see if we need to convert the type when assigning

                    if (type == typeof(Guid))
                        value = Guid.Parse(value.ToString());

                    pi.SetValue(parentObj, type != null ? Convert.ChangeType(value, type) : value);

                    if (pi.PropertyType != typeof(string) && IsContainerProperty(pi.PropertyType))
                        continue;
                    if (pi.PropertyType == typeToReturn)
                        objToLoad = value;

                }
                else if (!collectionProperties.ContainsKey(objKey) && IsContainerProperty(pi.PropertyType))
                {
                    var innerType = pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                    var add = pi.PropertyType.GetMethod("Add",
                            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public);


                    if (innerType.IsSimpleType())
                    {
                        collectionProperties[objKey] = valueToSet;
                        add.Invoke(value, new[] { valueToSet });

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Since we can't access the property 
                        var innerObj = createObject(innerType);
                        collectionProperties[objKey] = innerObj;
                        add.Invoke(value, new[] { innerObj });
                        if (innerType == typeToReturn)
                            objToLoad = innerObj;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
```

Can someone help me out with this?
I am also open to other suggestions to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any reflection here. Can you add that code?

Comment: Your code has a flaw btw. The string `a0000a0b0` will be detected as `isAllZeros`.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is downvoted. I mean, Priyank did some research, supplied code and so on. The goals are also clearly described, although the code and the question is a little contradicting, but I don't see why it'd give cause for a downvote.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Created an answer with my explanation of the flaw :)

Comment: Where exactly in the reflection code are you trying to invoke the conversion operator? I see no mention of "op_Implicit" or "op_Explicit" here.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I am not sure about it.The conversion operator is never called :(

Answer (score 1):

You could just put the code in the setter?

```
public class OrgName
{
    private string _value;
    private string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            bool isAllZeros = value?.All(x => x == '0') ?? false;
            if(isAllZeros)
            {
                _value = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                _value = value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Or maybe even in the getter.

Comment: Provided the goal is to find of a `value` is all zeroes, this would also do the trick: `set { _value = value.Trim("0").Length > 0 ? value : string.Empty; }`

Comment: @Heki yes the goal is to check if the value is all zeros then it should be displayed as a blank string.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an indirect solution to your problem as right now your code has a flaw.

Ex. `a0000a0b0` will be detected as `isAllZeros`

To explain any further what exactly the issue in your code is.

First let's look at this line:

```
bool isAllZeros = value.Where(x => char.IsDigit(x)).All(x => x == '0');
```

The first thing you do is taking `value` and performing a `Where` on it. The condition for the `where` to pass is that each value (`x`) is a digit. Which means that any non-digit characters such as `a`, `b`, `c` will be skipped.

As contrary to what you may have interpreted `Where` as then it just filters away any values that doesn't match the condition.

This means that values that aren't digits in your case will not pass and thus when the enumeration hits `All` then it will only enumerate the characters that are digits.

What your code is basically equivalent to in an English speaking is:

1. Take value
2. Skip all characters that aren't digits
3. Check if all digit characters are 0's

What you want your code to actually do is:

1. Take value
2. Check if all characters are digits and 0. In this case you actually only have to check if the character is `'0'`. The `char.IsDigit` check is redundant.

It could be solved by doing this:

```
bool isAllZeros = value.All(x => x == '0');
```

You might want to put in a null check in case `value` is null though.

```
bool isAllZeros = value?.All(x => x == '0') ?? false;
```

In case you aren't using C# 6

```
bool isAllZeros = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? false : value.All(x => x == '0');
```